# Keras: How to split y_pred and y_true into three

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras, and  want to use custom loss function

i'm triying to split y_pred and y_true into three part , each part length is 1/3 from original length

this is my code but return error ("nan" loss):

```
def create_loss_function_custom(len_train):
            tier_1 = int(len_train/3)
            tier_2 = int(len_train*2/3)
            def loss_function_custom(y_true, y_pred):
                y_pred_1 = y_pred[:, :tier_1]
                y_pred_2 = y_pred[:, tier_1:tier_2]
                y_pred_3 = y_pred[:, tier_2:]

                y_true_1 = y_true[:, :tier_1]
                y_true_2 = y_true[:, tier_1:tier_2]
                y_true_3 = y_true[:, tier_2:]

                loss_1= K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true_1,y_pred_1))
                loss_2 = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true_2,y_pred_2))
                loss_3 = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true_3, y_pred_3))


                return K.max([loss_1,loss_2,loss_3])
            return loss_function_custom
```

How to do this ?

i'm using theano backend

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: it's return "nan" loss

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong dimension. Usually, the first dimension is the sample index, so you probably want to do :
           `y_pred_1 = y_pred[:tier_1]`
`y_pred_2 = y_pred[tier_1:tier_2]`
`y_pred_3 = y_pred[tier_2:]`